# How to show that there is a finite submodel for each model of $\phi$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

How can I show that if we are restricted to finite structures and take a sentence$\phi$, then for each model $M$ of $\phi$ there is a substructure of $M$, which is a minimal model of $\phi$?

Is this something weaker than the existance of prime model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it not an application of the least number principle? (A variant of the induction principle in arithmetic).

Prime models are different beasts. A model is prime it is elementarily embeddable in every model of a given complete theory $T$. The notion is trivial for finite models. If $M$ is finite, $M$ is the unique model of Th$(M)$ up to isomorphism. (Hence every finite model $M$ is a prime model of Th$(M)$ -- the embedding is actually an isomorphism.)

Comment: Thank you! How can I use the least number principle to use this? You mean I take the class of models of $\phi$ and then just take the one whith the smallest cardinality? I thought this may not have to be a substructure of a given model...

Comment: hi @user850424; Primo's argument will work perfectly to find a specific substructure as well. if $M$ is a finite model of $\phi$, just look at a substructure $N\leqslant M$ that models $\phi$ and is of minimal possible size. any substructure of $N$ will also be a substructure of $M$, so $N$ will indeed be a minimal model of $\phi$